# UseEffect runs infinite renders in React (Maximum update depth exceeded)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I have a Cart component , and an array of Cards inside it.

Every time the user removes a product from the cart , I remove it from the localstorage ,
and also remove it from the UI.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from '../Layout';
import Card from '../Home/Card';
import { getCart } from './cartHelpers';

const Cart = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(getCart());
  }, [items]);

  const showItems = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>You have {`${items.length}`} items in your cart</h2>
        <hr />
        {items.map((prod, index) => (
          <Card key={prod._id}
            ....... />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const noItemsMsg = () => (
    <h2>
      Your cart is empty! <br /> <Link to='/shop'>Continue Shopping</Link>
    </h2>
  );



return (
    <Layout
      title='Shopping Cart'
      desc='Manage your cart items'
      className='container-fluid'
    >
      <div className='row'>
        <div className='col-6'>
          {items && items.length > 0 ? showItems(items) : noItemsMsg()}
        </div>

        <div className='col-6'>
          <p>
            Show Checkout Options / Shipping Address / Total / Update Quantity
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
    };

export default Cart;
```

and **Card.js** :

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Link, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import ShowImage from '../ShowImage';
import { addItemToCart, updateItem, removeItem } from '../Cart/cartHelpers';

const Card = ({product,
   .............
}) => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
  const [countHowManyCopies, setCountHowManyCopies] = useState(product.count);

  const showRemoveButton = () => {
    return (
      showRemoveProductBtn && (
        <button
          onClick={() => removeItem(product._id)}
          className='btn btn-outline-danger mt-2 mb-2'
        >
          Remove Product
        </button>
      )
    )
  };

  return (
    <div className={!showProductFullSize ? 'col-4 mb-3' : ''}>
      <div className='card'>
        <div className='card-header name'>{product.name}</div>
        <div className='card-body'>
  
  
          .............. // more code

          {showRemoveButton()}

          .............. // more code
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Whenever the user hits Remove Item button I get :

```
 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.
```

What would be the best approach to fix this ?

It happens because of this piece of code (`items` in the array):

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(getCart());
  }, [items]);
```

Comment: change the dependency array from `[items]` to `[items.length]`

Comment: Did you try [ ] instead of [items]

Comment: @AtifSaddique: Doesn't work , UI is not updated

Comment: The reason why it is creating an infinite loop is because you are setting the items inside the same effect and it runs when the value of items change. So as soon as you land inside the effect, the value of items is changed and effect run again, it change value again, run again and soo on....

Comment: @FridayAmeh: If we do that then the UI is never refreshed

Comment: You need to run your effect, when the return value of `getCart()` changes, not when `items` change, because items are being changed inside this effect.
Maybe try putting `[getCart()]` instead of `[items]`

Comment: Why not just render the result of `getCart()`? copying state is usually not a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cart.js file: remove items dependency from useEffect. import removeItem here

```
import { removeItem } from '../Cart/cartHelpers';

const Cart = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setItems(getCart());
  }, []);

// Add this function and pass it to Card component
const handleRemove = (id) => {
    removeItem(id)
    setItems(getCart())
  }

  const showItems = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>You have {`${items.length}`} items in your cart</h2>
        <hr />
        {items.map((prod, index) => (
          <Card key={prod._id} handleRemove={handleRemove}
            ....... />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };
```

Card.js - receive handleRemove as props

```
const Card = ({product, handleRemove
   .............
}) => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
  const [countHowManyCopies, setCountHowManyCopies] = useState(product.count);

  const showRemoveButton = () => {
    return (
      showRemoveProductBtn && (
        <button
          onClick={() => handleRemove(product._id)}
          className='btn btn-outline-danger mt-2 mb-2'
        >
          Remove Product
        </button>
      )
    )
  };...
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will get that "Maximum update depth exceeded" warning when the component is rendered, no need wait to click to Remove button.
The reason is: setItems will be called when items changes, then setItems will change the items, so it will cause an infinite recurse.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setItems(getCart());// setItems will change the items
  }, [items]);
```

Anw, I think the current approach is not clean approach as it is very hard to control component re-rendering by this way.
My suggestion is removing the use of useEffect, then add onRemoveItems as props of CardComponent

```
import { addItemToCart, updateItem, removeItem } from '../Cart/cartHelpers';

const Cart = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  //remove this
  //useEffect(() => {
  //  setItems(getCart());
  //}, [items]);
  const removeItem = (id) => {
    removeItem(id);
    setItems(getCart());
  }
  const showItems = () => {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>You have {`${items.length}`} items in your cart</h2>
        <hr />
        {items.map((prod, index) => (
          <Card key={prod._id} onRemoveItem={removeItem}
            ....... />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  };



const Card = ({product,
   .............
}) => {
  const [redirect, setRedirect] = useState(false);
  const [countHowManyCopies, setCountHowManyCopies] = useState(product.count);

  const showRemoveButton = () => {
    return (
      showRemoveProductBtn && (
        <button
          onClick={() => props.onRemoveItem(product._id)}
          className='btn btn-outline-danger mt-2 mb-2'
        >
          Remove Product
        </button>
      )
    )
  };

  return (
    <div className={!showProductFullSize ? 'col-4 mb-3' : ''}>
      <div className='card'>
        <div className='card-header name'>{product.name}</div>
        <div className='card-body'>
  
  
          .............. // more code

          {showRemoveButton()}

          .............. // more code
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of the problem is in the use of '**useEffect**' for updating state.

**useEffect** can be used for performing side-effects only.

A side effect is an activity that gets triggered as a result of change of state.

**Some examples of side-effects are:**

- Submit a form after user supplies the input data.
- Fetch JSON data from an API, when page loads.

**Updating the state inside *useEffect* can cause an infinite loop.**

---

The problem noticed is an example of the scenario of state being updated inside useEffect.

- Whenever **setItems** is called, the state of '**items**' gets
  changed.
- Change of state will trigger **useEffect** for the purpose of running
  side-effects.
- **useEffect** is calling **setItems** again, which is causing the infinite loop.

**How to solve the problem?**

The problem can be solved by removing the **useEffect** hook, as it is not necessary in the given scenario.